# load a json file from filestsystem to oracle database

Tags: javascript, java, json, oracle, oracle11g

I need to load JSON files that are on Linux filesystem to oracle database table.

I need to load each and every column of the JSON file into an appropriate column 
in oracle database table.

Is there a javascript to do that?

Comment: *Is there a java script to do that ?*

No

Comment: This is not a code writing service

Comment: First read json file and convert it into Map or java objects.Use library jackson or org.json or gson. Next use jdbc to create database, tables and fill in it.

Answer (score 1):

Using 12.1.0.2.0 or later given a JSON document like this

```
{
    "PONumber": 2286,
    "Reference": "ABANDA-20140803",
    "Requestor": "Amit Banda",
    "User": "ABANDA",
    "CostCenter": "A80",
    "ShippingInstructions": {
        "name": "Amit Banda",
        "Address": {
            "street": "Magdalen Centre, The Isis Science Park",
            "city": "Oxford",
            "county": "Oxon.",
            "postcode": "OX9 9ZB",
            "country": "United Kingdom"
        },
        "Phone": [
            {
                "type": "Office",
                "number": "861-555-4886"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Special Instructions": "Hand Carry",
    "LineItems": [
        {
            "ItemNumber": 1,
            "Part": {
                "Description": "Cookie's Fortune",
                "UnitPrice": 19.95,
                "UPCCode": 44004499323
            },
            "Quantity": 4.0
        }, {
            "ItemNumber": 2,
            "Part": {
                "Description": "A Bright Shining Lie",
                "UnitPrice": 19.95,
                "UPCCode": 26359122026
            },
            "Quantity": 4.0
        }, {
            "ItemNumber": 3,
            "Part": {
                "Description": "Karaoke: 25 Song Country Library Vol.1 201",
                "UnitPrice": 19.95,
                "UPCCode": 13023006096
            },
            "Quantity": 7.0
        }, {
            "ItemNumber": 4,
            "Part": {
                "Description": "Red Skelton: Lost Episodes",
                "UnitPrice": 19.95,
                "UPCCode": 18713811172
            },
            "Quantity": 4.0
        }, {
            "ItemNumber": 5,
            "Part": {
                "Description": "Stealing Home",
                "UnitPrice": 19.95,
                "UPCCode": 85391181828
            },
            "Quantity": 9.0
        }
    ]
}
```

You can do something like this..

```
G:\JSON\examples\loadDocumentToTable>sqlplus system/oracle@PDB12201 @loadDocumentToTable %CD% purchaseOrder.json

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu May 25 22:34:14 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Thu May 25 2017 22:33:29 -07:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> spool loadDocumentToTables.log
SQL> --
SQL> def USERNAME = JSON2RELATIONAL
SQL> --
SQL> def PASSWORD = &USERNAME
SQL> --
SQL> def JSONDIR = &1
SQL> --
SQL> def JSONFILE = &2
SQL> --
SQL> drop user &USERNAME cascade
  2  /
old   1: drop user &USERNAME cascade
new   1: drop user JSON2RELATIONAL cascade

User dropped.

SQL> grant connect, resource, create any directory, unlimited tablespace to &USERNAME identified by &PASSWORD
  2  /
old   1: grant connect, resource, create any directory, unlimited tablespace to &USERNAME identified by &PASSWORD
new   1: grant connect, resource, create any directory, unlimited tablespace to JSON2RELATIONAL identified by JSON2RELAT
IONAL

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect &USERNAME/&PASSWORD@&_connect_identifier
Connected.
SQL> --
SQL> create or replace directory JSONDIR as '&JSONDIR'
  2  /
old   1: create or replace directory JSONDIR as '&JSONDIR'
new   1: create or replace directory JSONDIR as 'G:\JSON\examples\loadDocumentToTable'

Directory created.

SQL> create table PURCHASEORDER_MASTER(
  2    PO_NUMBER        NUMBER(10)
  3   ,REQUESTOR        VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)
  4   ,USERID           VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
  5   ,COSTCENTER       VARCHAR2(16)
  6   ,SHIP_TO_NAME     VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
  7   ,SHIP_TO_STREET   VARCHAR2(38 CHAR)
  8   ,SHIP_TO_CITY     VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
  9   ,SHIP_TO_COUNTY   VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
 10   ,SHIP_TO_POSTCODE VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
 11   ,SHIP_TO_STATE    VARCHAR2(2 CHAR)
 12   ,SHIP_TO_PROVINCE VARCHAR2(2 CHAR)
 13   ,SHIP_TO_ZIP      VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
 14   ,SHIP_TO_COUNTRY  VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)
 15   ,SHIP_TO_PHONE    VARCHAR2(24 CHAR)
 16   ,INSTRUCTIONS     VARCHAR2(2048 CHAR)
 17  )
 18  /

Table created.

SQL> create table PURCHASEORDER_LINEITEM(
  2    PO_NUMBER        NUMBER(10)
  3   ,ITEMNO         NUMBER(38)
  4   ,DESCRIPTION       VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)
  5   ,UPCCODE        VARCHAR2(14 CHAR)
  6   ,QUANTITY  NUMBER(12,4)
  7   ,UNITPRICE         NUMBER(14,2)
  8  )
  9  /

Table created.

SQL> insert all
  2         WHEN (SEQ# = 1) -- Only for the first row output by JSONTABLE
  3         THEN INTO PURCHASEORDER_MASTER(
  4                PO_NUMBER,REQUESTOR,USERID,COSTCENTER,SHIP_TO_NAME,SHIP_TO_STREET,SHIP_TO_CITY,SHIP_TO_COUNTY,SHIP_TO
_POSTCODE,SHIP_TO_STATE,SHIP_TO_PROVINCE ,SHIP_TO_ZIP,SHIP_TO_COUNTRY,SHIP_TO_PHONE,INSTRUCTIONS
  5              )
  6              VALUES(
  7                PO_NUMBER,REQUESTOR,USERID,COSTCENTER,SHIP_TO_NAME,SHIP_TO_STREET,SHIP_TO_CITY,SHIP_TO_COUNTY,SHIP_TO
_POSTCODE,SHIP_TO_STATE,SHIP_TO_PROVINCE ,SHIP_TO_ZIP,SHIP_TO_COUNTRY,SHIP_TO_PHONE,INSTRUCTIONS
  8              )
  9         WHEN (1=1) -- For all rows output by JSONTABLE
 10         THEN INTO PURCHASEORDER_LINEITEM(
 11                PO_NUMBER,ITEMNO,DESCRIPTION,UPCCODE,QUANTITY,UNITPRICE
 12              )
 13              VALUES(
 14                PO_NUMBER,ITEMNO,DESCRIPTION,UPCCODE,QUANTITY,UNITPRICE
 15              )
 16  SELECT *
 17    FROM JSON_TABLE(
 18           BFILENAME('JSONDIR','PurchaseOrder.json'),
 19           '$'
 20           COLUMNS(
 21             PO_NUMBER        NUMBER(10)           path '$.PONumber',
 22             REFERENCE        VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)    path '$.Reference',
 23             REQUESTOR        VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)   path '$.Requestor',
 24             USERID           VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)    path '$.User',
 25             COSTCENTER       VARCHAR2(16)         path '$.CostCenter',
 26             SHIP_TO_NAME     VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)    path '$.ShippingInstructions.name',
 27             SHIP_TO_STREET   VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)    path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.street',
 28             SHIP_TO_CITY     VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)    path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.city',
 29             SHIP_TO_COUNTY   VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)    path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.county',
 30             SHIP_TO_POSTCODE VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)    path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.postcode',
 31             SHIP_TO_STATE    VARCHAR2(2 CHAR)     path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.state',
 32             SHIP_TO_PROVINCE VARCHAR2(2 CHAR)     path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.province',
 33             SHIP_TO_ZIP      VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)     path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.zipCode',
 34             SHIP_TO_COUNTRY  VARCHAR2(32 CHAR)    path '$.ShippingInstructions.Address.country',
 35             SHIP_TO_PHONE    VARCHAR2(24 CHAR)    path '$.ShippingInstructions.Phones[0].number',
 36             INSTRUCTIONS     VARCHAR2(2048 CHAR)  path '$.SpecialInstructions',
 37             NESTED PATH '$.LineItems[*]'
 38             columns (
 39               SEQ#             for ordinality,
 40               ITEMNO         NUMBER(38)           path '$.ItemNumber',
 41               DESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(256 CHAR)   path '$.Part.Description',
 42               UPCCODE        VARCHAR2(14 CHAR)    path '$.Part.UPCCode',
 43               QUANTITY       NUMBER(12,4)         path '$.Quantity',
 44               UNITPRICE      NUMBER(14,2)         path '$.Part.UnitPrice'
 45             )
 46           )
 47         )
 48  /

6 rows created.

SQL> set lines 256 trimspool off pages 50
SQL> COLUMN DESCRIPTION FORMAT A32
SQL> COLUMN INSTRUCTIONS FORMAT A32
SQL> --
SQL> select *
  2    FROM PURCHASEORDER_MASTER
  3  /

 PO_NUMBER REQUESTOR
            USERID     COSTCENTER       SHIP_TO_NAME         SHIP_TO_STREET
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------- ---------- ---------------- -------------------- --------------------------------------
SHIP_TO_CITY                     SHIP_TO_COUNTY                   SHIP_TO_POSTCODE                 SH SH SHIP_TO_ SHIP_T
O_COUNTRY                  SHIP_TO_PHONE            INSTRUCTIONS
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------- -- -- -------- ------
-------------------------- ------------------------ --------------------------------
      2286 Amit Banda
            ABANDA     A80              Amit Banda           Magdalen Centre, The Isis Science Park
Oxford                           Oxon.                            OX9 9ZB                                 United Kingdom



SQL> select *
  2    FROM PURCHASEORDER_LINEITEM
  3  /

 PO_NUMBER     ITEMNO DESCRIPTION                      UPCCODE          QUANTITY  UNITPRICE
---------- ---------- -------------------------------- -------------- ---------- ----------
      2286          1 Cookie's Fortune                 44004499323             4      19.95
      2286          2 A Bright Shining Lie             26359122026             4      19.95
      2286          3 Karaoke: 25 Song Country Library 13023006096             7      19.95
                       Vol.1 201

      2286          4 Red Skelton: Lost Episodes       18713811172             4      19.95
      2286          5 Stealing Home                    85391181828             9      19.95

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

G:\JSON\examples\loadDocumentToTable>
```